# Play Framework 2 HornetQ

Tags: playframework-2.0, hornetq

Can I integrate Play Framework 2.0 with HornetQ ?
I have a HornetQ server running and I want to consume messages from my Play web application.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You have to add the HornetQ client dependency in your `project/Build.scala` [dependency file](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SBTDependencies).

You can configure your HornetQ client in the `onStart()` method of the [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal).

Then, in a Play controller or any class you want, you can send messages to your HornetQ broker, like you'd do in a standard Java EE app.